# Can i have help on how i can save a foreignkey in a model?

Tags: django, foreign-keys

I have two models `Order` and `OrderItem`.

The process to make an order starts with the `OrderItem` model.

```
 class OrderItem(SmartModel):
        shopping_id = models.CharField(max_length=50,db_index=True)
        quantity = models.IntegerField(default=0)
        item = models.ForeignKey(Item)
        order = models.ForeignKey(Order,null=True,blank=True)
```

`OrderItem` represents an item and is a modelform with one field being `quantity` others are `excluded`
i validate the form and create the item like so,

```
def show_item(request,id):
    # need to evaluate the HTTP method
    if request.method == 'POST':
        a = Item.objects.get(pk=id)
        form = PartialOrderItemForm(request.POST,instance=a)
        # check validation of posted data
        if form.is_valid():
            order.add_to_order(request,a)
            # if test cookie worked, get rid of it
            if request.session.test_cookie_worked():
                request.session.delete_test_cookie()
            url =urlresolvers.reverse('order_index')
            # redirect to order page
            return HttpResponseRedirect(url)
    else:
        form = PartialOrderItemForm()
    request.session.set_test_cookie()
    context={

        'form':form,

    }
    return render_to_response('item.html',context,context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

the function called after `is_valid` i.e `order.add_to_order` creates and saves an item.

```
def add_to_order(request,obj):  
    postdata = request.POST.copy()
    #get quantity added, return 0 if empty
    quantity = postdata.get('quantity',0)
    # fetch the item or return  missing page error_message
    i = get_object_or_404(Item,pk=obj.id)
    # get items in order
    order_items = get_order_items(request)
    item_in_orders = False
    # check to see if item is already in order
    for order_item in order_items:
        if order_item.item.id == i.id:
            #update the quantity if found
            order_item.augment_quantity(quantity)
            item_in_orders = True
    if not item_in_orders:
        # creat and save a new order item
        anon_user = User.objects.get(id=settings.ANONYMOUS_USER_ID)
    oi=OrderItem.objects.create(shopping_id=_shopping_id(request),
                                          quantity=quantity,
                                          item=i,
                                          created_by=anon_user,
                                          modified_by=anon_user)
    oi.save()
```

when a customer is done creating an item(in the database), they fill in a form which is `Order`

```
class Order(SmartModel):
    #each individual status
    SUBMITTED = 1 # the credit card was valid or mobilemoney was recieved.It is ready for us to process the order
    PROCESSED = 2 # After submitted orders are reviewed, we can mark them as processed, letting deliverers know order is ready to be shipped
    DELIVERED = 3 # the order has been processed and approved by the adminstrator(in this case us), it is delivered.
    PICKED_UP =4 # the order has been processed and is picked up by customer
    CANCELLED = 5 # Customer called the company and decided they didnt want to go through with the order either by phone or email.

    # SET OF POSSIBLE STATUSES
    ORDER_STATUSES = ((SUBMITTED,'Submitted'),(PROCESSED,'Processed'),(DELIVERED,'Delivered'),(PICKED_UP,'picked_up'),(CANCELLED,'Cancelled'),)
    #Order info
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    status = models.IntegerField(choices=ORDER_STATUSES, default=SUBMITTED)
#   customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer,null=True,blank=True,help_text="The customer who made this order",default=None,)
    restaurant = models.ForeignKey(Restaurant,null=True,blank=True,default = None,help_text="The restaurant the customer order from")
    #contact info
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=50,help_text="Needed as alternative")
    mobile = PhoneNumberField(max_length=20,default='+25078######',help_text="Needed to communicate and confirm payment from mobile money")

    #billing information
    billing_name= models.CharField(max_length=50,help_text="Needed so we can deliver to the right individual")

    billing_address= models.CharField(max_length=50,help_text="Needed for delivery purposes, should be office address.")    
    billing_city = models.CharField(max_length=50,help_text="F4L services are only in selected cities.")
```

`Order` is a modelform that i validate and save like so.

```
def show_checkout(request):
    if order.is_empty(request):
        cart_url = urlresolvers.reverse('order_index')
        return HttpResponseRedirect(cart_url)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        postdata = request.POST.copy()
        form = forms.CheckoutForm(request.POST,postdata)
        if form.is_valid():
            anon_user = User.objects.get(id=settings.ANONYMOUS_USER_ID)
            obj = form.save(commit=False)
            obj.created_by = anon_user
            obj.modified_by = anon_user
            obj.save()
            if postdata['submit'] == 'place order':
                reciept_url = urlresolvers.reverse('checkout_reciept')
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reciept_url)
    else:
        form = forms.CheckoutForm
    context = {
        'form':form,
    }
    return render_to_response('checkout/checkout.html',context,context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

i should point out that `OrderItem` is called before `Order`..much of where the confusion is coming from
to return all `OrderItem` objects related to `Order` i do as suggested by the django documentation https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward

```
>>> from orders.models import OrderItem,Order
>>> a = Order.objects.get(id=1)
>>> a
<Order: blah blah blahbaah@blahblah.com +250780000000 1 2013-02-26 17:25:23.138738+00:00>
>>> a.orderitem_set.all()
[]
```

I am thinking its empty because i didnt save the foreignkey, but i am really confused about how to go about that. Any help is appreciated..

Comment: is add_to_order a method on the Order model?

Comment: no its on the `OrderItem` model.

Comment: friendly suggestion, you may want to simplify your question there's like a lot of text/code to parse up there ^

Comment: @DavidLam i understand man.. sorry about that, didnt want to live anything out..will do better next time

Answer (score 0):

You just need to pass in (or somehow obtain) the object for the order.

Assuming the PK of the order is in your POST vars, you could do this:

```
def add_to_order(request,obj):  
    postdata = request.POST.copy()
    order = Order.objects.get(pk=postdata.get('order_id'))
    …
        oi=OrderItem.objects.create(order=order, shopping_id=_shopping_id(request), …)
```

Based on your comment below though, you're creating your `order` AFTER you create the `orderitem`, making the code above pointless.

If the order hasn't been created yet, there's absolutely no way for you to tie the order item to the order. At least not without doing something else.

Here's what I'd do.

1. Add a new field to your OrderItem:

   ```
   order_uuid = models.CharField(max_length=25, blank=False, null=True)
   ```
2. When you start your order process (wherever you start it), create a UUID using python's `uuid` package:

   ```
   import uuid
   temporary_order_uuid = uuid.uuid4()
   ```
3. Pass this value through each of your order steps, final saving it to the `orderitem` when you create it.

   ```
   oi=OrderItem.objects.create(order_uuid=temporary_order_uuid, …)
   ```
4. After you create your `order`, go back and update all `orderitems` that contain that uuid with the order's pk:

   ```
   order_items = OrderItems.objects.get(order_uuid=temporary_order_uuid)
   for oi in order_items:
       oi.order = order
       oi.save()
   ```
5. A much cleaner solution would be to create your `orderitems` AFTER you create the order in the database, but I don't know all the various requirements of your app.

Comment: i dont think this is gon work because the Pk of order is not in `postdata`. am sorry i didn't mention `Order` is created after OrderItem. but hey let me just try it...

Comment: Well, that won't work then. If you create order AFTER you create OrderItem, you'll have an issue. I'll update my answer with an idea.

Comment: well am gon check this out, it could take me sometime but when am done i will post of it works or not....thanks for your time.

Comment: so am still having issues implementing what you suggested, how about we ponder on poin `5` in the mean time. what requirements do you need to know.

Comment: Why are you creating the order items before you create the order?

Comment: so the things..when a customer uses the app, they order for items(`OrderItem`) then when they click checkout,they have to fill in a form that collects info such contacts e.t.c `Order`. thats the logic i am using.

Comment: OK, you need to post more of your code so I can see what you're doing. I need to see all views involved in order creation. Remove code you've commented out.

Comment: OK. This will have to wait till tomorrow. I've got a deadline.

Comment: do you think you can go with this